# Find Directories With No Files in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have a list of directories

```
/home
  /dir1
  /dir2
  ...
  /dir100
```

Some of them have no files in it. How can I use Unix `find` to do it?

I tried

```
find . -name "*" -type d -size 0
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does your find have predicate `-empty`?

You should be able to use `find . -type d -empty`

Answer (score 2):

If you're a zsh user, you can always do this. If you're not, maybe this will convince you:

```
echo **/*(/^F)
```

`**/*` will expand to every child node of the present working directory and the `()` is a glob qualifier. `/` restricts matches to directories, and `F` restricts matches to non-empty ones. Negating it with `^` gives us all empty directories. See the [zshexpn](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) man page for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`-empty` reports empty leaf dirs.
If you want to find empty trees then have a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/fslint/source/browse/trunk/fslint/finded

Note that script can't be used without the other support scripts,
but you might want to install fslint and use it directly?

Comment: Note also that if you intend to delete the directories, then `find . -depth -type d -empty -delete` can be used to delete entire empty subtrees

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

. and .. both count as a link, as do files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Pimin Konstantin Kefalou prints folders with only 2 links and other files (d, f, ...).

The easiest way I have found is:

```
for directory in $(find . -type d); do
   if [ -n "$(find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f)" ]; then echo "$directory"
   fi
done
```

If you have name with spaces use quotes in "$directory".

You can replace . by your reference folder.

I haven't been able to do it with one find instruction.