# Find directories without files but with subfolders in Unix

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

I work with AIX 5.3 (ksh) and I'm looking for a way to find all folders that contain subfolders but **without** any files in it.

I found a solution for searching empty directories ([Find Directories With No Files in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909669/find-directories-with-no-files-in-unix-linux)) but this doesn't work if subfolders are also necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following script:

```
find . -type d | while read d; do
   nf=$(ls -lA $d | grep -c "^-")
   nd=$(ls -lA $d | grep -c "^d")
   [[ $nf -eq 0 && $nd -gt 0 ]] && echo $d
done
```